# Regex pattern for matching words between two delimiters

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a regex pattern to match words between two dots **.** For example `Grade 4.Maths.English`is pattern to be matched. It should Ignore `Grade 3.Demo Adaptive Module.Mathematics` which also has Math. The pattern I tried is

```
".+\.(Math.*)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

but it matches both `Grade 4.Maths.English` and `Grade 3.Demo Adaptive Module.Mathematics`

More Examples

Patterns to be matched:

```
Grade 8.Maths Test.Maths
Grade 8.Maths Test.Maths 
Grade 6.Maths Formative Assessment.NA
```

Patterns to be ignored

```
Grade 3.Multiplication  new.Mathematics
Grade 3.Demo Adaptive Module.Mathematics
Grade 4.Poetry.English
Maths 4.Primary.Maths
Maths 5.Primary.Concepts
```

Comment: Please provide more examples of both strings that should match and of strings that should not match.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the examples.

Comment: @AdrianHHH have edited the questions now

Comment: Only thing I notice is that there is a space after your second `Grade 8.Maths Test.Maths `. To allow this, you need to add something like `\s*` before `$` end. Further an idea to use `^` start anchor which improves performance. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U7D4jE/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the "math" between two dots use `\.math[^.]*\.`.

To match the whole string use `^.*\.math[^.]*\..*$`. This version allows extra dots at the start and end.

To match the whole string use `^[^.]*\.math[^.]*\.[^.]*$`. This version only allows two dots.

Note that `[^.]*` matches zero or more characters that are not a dot.

If you need to capture the various parts of the matched string for later use then add capture brackets. For example `^([^.]*)\.math([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$` will capture the text before the first dot in `$1` the text after the last dot in `$3` and the text between "math" and the last dot in `$2`. Note that some regex implementations use `\1`, `\2` and `\3` rather than the `$1` etc forms.

Comment: the pattern doesn't match if the word is in the middle for example Grade 8.English Math Word.English. Sorry that I didn't include the example in the question

Comment: That was not a requirement in the question. All of the examples show dot immediately followed by "math"

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
^.*\.[^.\n]*Math[^.\n]*\..*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTEhew/1)

The explanation in the `regex101` will be good enough to explain the
behavior of the regex.
The regex flavor above is mostly `ERE` (except for the `\n` expression) and will work
with most platforms.